# How to I custom my log format in winston-papertrail?

Tags: javascript, typescript, winston, papertrail-app

I am making an app based on typescript and trying to implement `winston-papertrail` for logs with a timestamp and custom format. The problem is that when I am consoling it, it is showing exacltly what I want but on `papertrail` it is showing in an unexpected way. Here is my code on the typescript.

```
const { Papertrail } = require("winston-papertrail");

const { createLogger, format, transports } = require("winston");
const { combine, timestamp, prettyPrint, printf } = format;

const timezoned = () => {
    return new Date().toLocaleString("en-US", {
        timeZone: "Asia/Kolkata",
    });
};

const myFormat = printf(({ level, message, timestamp }) => {
    return `${timestamp} ${level}: ${message}`;
});
const options = {
    console: {
        level: "debug",

        format: combine(
            timestamp({format: timezoned}),
            myFormat,
        ) ,
    },
};

const winstonPapertrail = new Papertrail({
    host: "logs3.papertrailapp.com",
    port: 32795,

    level: "info",
});

const consoleWinston = new transports.Console(options.console);

export const logger = createLogger({
    transports: [winstonPapertrail, consoleWinston],
});
```

How I am getting it on the console (which is the correct format) :

```
10/26/2019, 11:15:49 PM info: Fetching offset:16000 count:1000
10/26/2019, 11:15:59 PM info: Products Fetched
10/26/2019, 11:15:59 PM info: Indexing Products
```

How it is showing on papertrail:

```
Oct 26 23:15:50 wolborg default info     { message: 'Fetching offset:16000 count:1000', 
Oct 26 23:15:50 wolborg default info       level: 'info', 
Oct 26 23:15:50 wolborg default info       [Symbol(level)]: 'info', 
Oct 26 23:15:50 wolborg default info       [Symbol(message)]: 
Oct 26 23:15:50 wolborg default info        '{"message":"Fetching offset:16000 count:1000","level":"info"}' } 
Oct 26 23:15:59 wolborg default info Products Fetched 
Oct 26 23:15:59 wolborg default info     { message: 'Products Fetched', 
Oct 26 23:15:59 wolborg default info       level: 'info', 
Oct 26 23:15:59 wolborg default info       [Symbol(level)]: 'info', 
Oct 26 23:15:59 wolborg default info       [Symbol(message)]: '{"message":"Products Fetched","level":"info"}' } 
Oct 26 23:15:59 wolborg default info Indexing Products 
Oct 26 23:15:59 wolborg default info     { message: 'Indexing Products', 
Oct 26 23:15:59 wolborg default info       level: 'info', 
Oct 26 23:15:59 wolborg default info       [Symbol(level)]: 'info', 
Oct 26 23:15:59 wolborg default info       [Symbol(message)]: '{"message":"Indexing Products","level":"info"}' }
```

Comment: You didn't provide the format to the papertrail transport, why is that unexpected?

Comment: how am I supposed to provide the format that, please tell

Comment: Well what do their docs say? I'd imagine it's similar to how you set up the other transport.

Comment: that is what I am asking, do I provide format so that the logs would print in a single line